# First order ODE with hidden dependencies

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the ODE

$G'+f'(x)[k-G]=0$

where $G=G(g)$ and $x=x(g,h)$. I would like to solve for $G(g)$, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Is there a method to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dG(g)}{dg}+\frac{df(x)}{dx}\left(k-G(g)\right)=0$$
where $x=x(g,h)$, say $x=\varphi(g,h)$

First, we have to make clear what is known and what is unknown.

I suppose that the functions $f(x)$ and $\varphi(g,h)$ are known, while $G(g)$ is unknown.

$f(x)=f\left(\varphi(g,h)\right)=F(g,h)$is a known function.

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial g}$

Thus $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}}{\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial g}}$ is a known function, say $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\phi(g,h)$

Considere an antiderivative $\Phi(g,h)=\int \phi(g,h)dg$ which then is a known function.

$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\phi(g,h)=\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial g}$ is a known function.

The ODE can be written as : $$\frac{dG(g)}{dg}+\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial g}\left(k-G(g)\right)=0$$

There is no longer hidden dependency in the ODE which solution is :
$$G(g)=k+c\:e^{\Phi(g,h)}$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant and $\Phi(g,h)$ is the known function related with $f\left(x(g,h)\right)$ which is known thanks to the successive above relationships.

Since an extra variable $h$ appears in the wording of the problem, necessarily the result $G(g)$ also includes the extra variable $h$ and better should be written $G(g,h)$. The correct typing of the initial ODE should be :
$$\frac{\partial G(g,h)}{\partial g}+\frac{df(x)}{dx}\left(k-G(g,h)\right)=0$$